# Antonym for 'serial', as in 'a serial publication'

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, antonyms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word that signifies the opposite of a serial publication, where a serial publication is described like:

> The first novella in a three-part series.

Or:

> A quarterly publication.

The British expression "one-off" accurately describes the concept, but it seems more colloquial and dismissive, i.e., something that is meant as a draft or a prototype, than what I'm looking for. Surely this word exists.

A use case would be publishing a short-form comic or zine. Some issues would be serial: it will take 3 or 6 (or at least more than one) issues to cover a storyline. Others will be "one-off": it will only take one issue or strip or panel to cover a storyline.

Comment: Could you provide some more context around how exactly you would like to use this word?

Comment: 'one-off' works fine but is primarily British (it's slowly becoming more popular in the US). The great majority of works have a default presentation and it's usually a single volume rather than multiple/serial. So usually one need not mention anything unless it _is_ serial. That is, if 'serial' is not used, no need to use an antonym, it is so by default.

Comment: For comic books, you can use "[one-shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_%28comics%29)".

Comment: @Mitch That makes a lot of sense, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I live in the US, I sometimes use and often hear the term "one-off", it is the first thing that came to mind when I saw the title of this question, and I never would have thought that it was British or that it referred to a draft or prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain-specific relational antonym of 'serial publication' is 'volume publication'. This works for the use case you describe, and is the traditional oppository phrase. It is inexact (not surprisingly: all antonyms are inexact, and relational antonyms particularly so), hence constructions such as "serial volume" are not only possible but in widespread use.

Comment: Selected because of the domain specificity.

Answer (score 27):

"One-off" is, as you say, slightly British.

"Stand-alone" is frequently used in Britain and North America.

"[One-shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_%28comics%29)" is also used for comics.

Comment: +1 for *stand-alone* (since I am in the US). An online dictionary link would enhance the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't mind not having the dictionary link, but include the [one-shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_%28comics%29) link from above since it directly relates to comics, and maybe incorporate Mitch's commentary, and you're golden.

Answer (score 19):

A publication that is not serial is a **one-time** publication. This usage beats out *stand-alone* even in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stand-alone%20publication%2Cone-time%20publication&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3)’s American corpus. It is official terminology for [Canada Post](http://www.dqglossary.com/annual%20or%20one-time%20publication.html), though lumped together for postal purposes with *annual publication.* The term is also sometimes used in [a slightly different sense](https://books.google.com/books?id=fOoGmYvuQGsC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=%22one-time%20publication%22&source=bl&ots=6O-1ZSwT49&sig=Mvsj_d4KceyHJlg7zk39KTj53Mc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwA2oVChMIhK-4-_qexwIVjbCACh0aAA3O#v=onepage&q=%22one-time%20publication%22&f=false), though, associated with the granting or selling of publication *rights* by an author to a publisher.

Answer (score 6):

For a one time publication of either a scholarly or casual work you can use the term Monograph.

Answer (score 5):

For a magazine, I would use **Special edition**

> Example: We are currently working on a special edition of The Lancet
>   to promote the latest thinking on this critical issue.

Comment: I'm not exactly looking to call attention to the fact that a particular issue is special, just that it's not part of a series.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you plan to use it, How about "[Ad-Hoc](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc)"?

> for the particular end or case at hand without consideration of wider application

Reference:
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc

Comment: I don't like "ad-hoc"; it sounds like you're just making things up as you go.

Answer (score 0):

The word Hapax Legomenon could be used.

> **[Hapax Legomenon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hapax%20legomenon)** -a word or form occurring only once in a document or corpus